# Accordion control for windows 8 metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro, custom-controls

How can I create a Accordion control for windows metro apps in XAML ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the techniques to create an accordion is by using  [`ZeroProximity.Accordion`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZeroProximity.Accordion/). It's a port of the [Silverlight Toolkit](https://silverlight.codeplex.com/) `<Accordion>` control.

You can add this package to your project via

- Package Manager Console: `PM> Install-Package ZeroProximity.Accordion`
- the NuGet Package Manager UI
- the NuGet website: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZeroProximity.Accordion/

---

Simply add a reference at the top of your XAML file:

```
xmlns:controls="using:ZeroProximity.Controls"
```

And then you can use the controls by using `<controls:...`

`<controls:Accordion>...</controls:Accordion>`,
`<controls:AccordionItem>...</controls:AccordionItem>` etc.

---

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
<controls:Accordion HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="ZeroOrOne">                       
    <controls:AccordionItem Header="IPL Teams" FontSize="35">
        <controls:AccordionItem.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="India"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Australia"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Bangladesh"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Pakistan"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:AccordionItem.Content>
    </controls:AccordionItem>
    <controls:AccordionItem Header="IPL Teams" FontSize="35">
        <controls:AccordionItem.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="India" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Australia"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Bangladesh"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Pakistan"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:AccordionItem.Content>
    </controls:AccordionItem>
</controls:Accordion>
```

*As at when this was edited (1 Dec 2016), no official documentation or website can be found regarding this package.